# How can I set a delegate without using segue.destinationViewController as the receiver to the setDelegate Method?

Tags: objective-c, ios, delegates, protocols

When using delegates, I usually only tell the next viewcontroller over in the UINavigationController that I want to set self as the delegate. I do this in my prepareForSegue method:

```
- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    [segue.destinationViewController setDelegate:self];
}
```

This has always worked great. However, I'm trying to tell a viewController two indexes or two views over in the navController, that I want to set self as the delegate. I've tried every way that I can think of define the viewController receiver that I want to send the setDelegate method to but nothing seems to be working. Here is one example that Ive tried:

```
    DateSelectViewController *dsvc = [[DateSelectViewController alloc] init];
    [dsvc setDelegate:self];
```

The method is never being delegated and I know it has to do with the way I'm setting the delegate because I've ruled out every other possibility. How can I do this correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do that directly because that view controller doesn't exist yet. What you can do is this in the next one along:

```
[segue.destinationViewController setDelegate:self.delegate];
```

If you have `A` -> `B` -> `C`

in `A` you'd have your original code:

```
- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    [segue.destinationViewController setDelegate:self];
    // self == A
}
```

In `B` you'd have:

```
- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    [segue.destinationViewController setDelegate:self.delegate];
    // self.delegate == A
}
```